# Python: convention name for a test

Tags: python, python-unittest

Is there a convention for naming tests in Python when using the `unittest` module. I know that each method inside a class which inherits from `unittest.TestCase` should start with test, but I wonder what is much better:

**1. A short descriptive name without docstring**

```
def test_for_a_date_on_a_weekday(self):
        customer_type = "Regular"
        dates = ["16Mar2009(mon)"]
    self.assertEquals(self.hotel_reservation_system.find_cheapest_hotel(customer_type, dates), "Lakewood")
```

**2. A number following the word test with a docstring which explains the test.**

```
def test_1(self):
    """Tests the cheapest hotel when the date is on a weekday.
    """
    customer_type = "Regular"
    dates = ["16Mar2009(mon)"]
    self.assertEquals(self.hotel_reservation_system.find_cheapest_hotel(customer_type, dates), "Lakewood")
```

Which option is much preferable, and if any of them what should I use?

Comment: Always opt for descriptive. Your tests are a way of providing a form of documentation to provide context on how the code works and what is being tested. It makes it more readable.

Comment: So, it means option number two, or should I make a mix, i.e., a short descriptive name with a docstring?

Comment: You don't necessarily need to have a docstring in each of your test methods as well. The name of your methods should be descriptive, but concise. However, this is definitely something that can also be a matter of opinion and I'm sure there are arguments for each side. :)

Comment: For myself, my goal is to make each of my unit tests as concise as possible, therefore I'm able to name my test methods fairly easily since they are responsible for testing one thing only at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Generally it is preferable to increase readability by :
    - choosing an adequate name     
    - describing how it works
```

Choose your name such that it will be short and descriptive. For readability, use snake_case. For example : test_week_date.

Always include a docstring in your function. This will allow the reader to get all necessary information if the name isn't clear enough OR if he doesn't really understand what the method does / how she does it.

Conclusion : short and descriptive (snake_case) name with a docstring.

Comment: Not for method names. You should be using snake_case: `test_week_date`, per PEP8: "Function names should be lowercase, with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability."

Comment: Right ! I'm used to use camelCase for regular functions, snake_case for methods (I was thought that). I'll edit;

Comment: Typically, in Python you will see camel case for class names and exception names: `MyClass`, `MyException`.